# Parent Page shows through Filter Menus in RadWindow embedded RadGrid

Tags: telerik, radgrid, radwindow, radmenu

I have a RadGrid in a RadWindow set to Modal.

I'm seeing two issues.

The first and most critical ONLY HAPPENS IN IE7 and NOT in FIREFOX is that the Filter Menus of the RadGrid do not display when clicked. Instead a box the size of the menus is opened through which I can see the parent page.

The second and probably related HAPPENS IN BOTH IE AND FIREFOX is that when I drag the RadWindow the content of the RadWindow disappears and is replaced by the same transparency to the parent page.

Any help you could offer would be great. I've spent all day hunting and pecking through CSS trying to find it.

Grid and window declarations follow.

```
    <telerik:RadWindowManager 
OnClientClose="OnViewerClose"
Behaviors="Close, Move, Resize,Maximize" 
ID="RadWindowManager" 
DestroyOnClose="true"
Opacity="99" 
runat="server">
    <Windows>
        <telerik:RadWindow 
            ID="AssociateUserWindow" 
            VisibleOnPageLoad="false" 
            Width="600"
            Height="400"
            runat="server"
            Overlay="true"
            KeepInScreenBounds="true"
            Modal="true"
            Skin="WebBlue">
        </telerik:RadWindow>
    </Windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>

        <telerik:RadGrid 
        ID="rgUsers" 
        runat="server" 
        AllowPaging="true" 
        AllowSorting="true" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        CellPadding="1" 
        CellSpacing="2" 
        GridLines="Vertical" 
        Skin="WebBlue"
        Width="100%"
        OnItemDataBound="rgUsers_ItemDataBound"
        OnNeedDataSource="rgUsers_NeedDataSource"
        PageSize="5"


        >
        <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages"></PagerStyle>
        <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="UserId" AllowMultiColumnSorting="True" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" HierarchyDefaultExpanded="true">
            <Columns>...ommitted...</Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I've found the issue... that opacity setting was the culprit. Removing it from the radwindow manager fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to extract a runnable sample that displays the issue? If you can I think the best thing to do here, since the markup that you posted looks completely fine, is to submit this in a support ticket over at [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com). Their support guys will probably be the best to figure out what the issue might be.